# How to troubleshoot a shared state issue in NUnit unit tests with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging dependency injection in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

I have an `IHostedService` using `ILogger` (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) injected with DI. The service runs every 60 seconds, the Timer class is used to accomplish this. I verify that the logger has been called once. In an `[OneTimeSetup]` method I create a mock of `ILogger<Type>`.
This has been done this way in many different unit tests. But after writing a second test (same test project, same project but different classes are being tested) where I also need to inject ILogger, the first test fails. If I execute only the tests in the first tests class, everything works.

Edit: I tested a bit, and I figured out that the test only fails when

- Run in debug mode
- Run in combination with another test class

First I tried to figure out if there is any shared state:

- In both test classes I am using an `OneTimeSetup` method
- in both classes I create **new** mock objects.

```cs
internal sealed class TestOne
{
    private Mock<ILogger<ClassToTest>> _logger;
    private ClassToTest _classToTest;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        _logger = new();

        _classToTest = new(_logger.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void StartAsync_CannotContinue_LogInformation()
    {
        // Act
        _classToTest.StartAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>());

        // Assert
        _logger.Verify(logger => logger.Log(
            It.Is<LogLevel>(logLevel => logLevel == LogLevel.Information),
            It.IsAny<EventId>(),
            It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
            It.IsAny<Exception>(),
            It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>()),
        Times.Once);
    }
}


internal sealed class TestTwo
{
    private Mock<ILogger<AnotherClassToTest>> _logger;
    private AnotherClassToTest _anotherClassToTest;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        _logger = new();

        _anotherClassToTest = new(_logger.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void SomeMethod_IsSuccessfull_LogInfo()
    {
        // Act
        _anotherClassToTest.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>());

        // Assert
        _logger.Verify(logger => logger.Log(
            It.Is<LogLevel>(logLevel => logLevel == LogLevel.Information),
            It.IsAny<EventId>(),
            It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
            It.IsAny<Exception>(),
            It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>()),
        Times.Once);
    }
}
```

After I removed the failing test (TestOne), another test begins running forever (also in TestOne). I needed to manually close VS so the test stops executing.

This is the exception I'm getting (from class TestOne) when running the tests together:

```
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times:
logger => logger.Log<It.IsAnyType>(It.Is<LogLevel>(logLevel => (int)logLevel == 2),
It.IsAny<EventId>(),
It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(),
It.IsAny<Exception>(),
It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>())
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a few days I found a proper solution to the problem.

The test class A had, what it looks like, a locking problem. I needed to add the [`[Parallelizable]` attribute](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/parallelizable.html). After this everyhting ran succesfully.

I'm guessing by using the same object and by using async await my tests deadlocked because they tried to update the same thing at the same time.